# How to migrate to callback nodejs

Tags: node.js, callback, request, asynccallback

I need to transform this code into clean code that uses callbacks, because this code does not allow me to use body information elsewhere.

```js
const endpoints = [];

function getDevicesFromPartnerCloud() {
  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://database-dcda.restdb.io/rest/endpoints',
    headers: {
      'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      'x-apikey': '*****************************'
    }
  };
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    data.forEach(function(data, index) {
      let endpoint = createSceneEndpoint(data._id, data.name);
      endpoints.push(endpoint);
    });
  });
  return endpoints;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cleanest way to do it would be to use a Promise to handle the asynchronous `request`. One of the most important things to remember is that functions should ideally do only one thing. That way, they are easier to test, reason about, and refactor. I would pull the code that actually makes the request into a separate function and have it return the body, then have your `getDevicesFromPartnerCloud` call that new function, get the data back, and process it however it wants. Most importantly, this "frees" the data from being stuck in the `request` callback, because you're wrapping it in a promise, and resolving it when the data is available.

Something like:

```
const endpoints = [];

function requestDevices() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://database-dcda.restdb.io/rest/endpoints',
      headers: {
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'x-apikey': '*****************************',
      },
    };

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error)
      }

      resolve({ response: response, body: body });
    });
  });
}

async function getDevicesFromPartnerCloud() {
  const devicesResponse = await requestDevices();
  const data = JSON.parse(devicesResponse.body);
  data.forEach(function(data, index) {
    const endpoint = createSceneEndpoint(data._id, data.name);
    endpoints.push(endpoint);
  });

  // Do whatever else you need with devicesResponse.body

  return endpoints;
}
```

If you wanted to go more of an es6 direction, maybe something like

```
let endpoints;

const requestDevices = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(
      {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://database-dcda.restdb.io/rest/endpoints',
        headers: {
          'cache-control': 'no-cache',
          'x-apikey': '*****************************',
        },
      },
      (error, response, body) => (error ? reject(error) : resolve(body)),
    );
  });

const getDevicesFromPartnerCloud = async () => {
  try {
    const body = await requestDevices();
    const data = JSON.parse(body);
    endpoints = data.map(({ _id, name }) =>
      createSceneEndpoint(_id, name),
    );

    // Do whatever else you need with devicesResponse.body
    // doStuff(body)

    return endpoints;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```